# Methods to switch from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: https

Would like to switch one of my web applications over to HTTP instead of being configured for HTTPS.

Couldn't find anything in the CA UI for this change...only thing i can think of doing is re creating the web application....

Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle both HTTPS and HTTP on the same web application. What you are looking at is Alternate Access Mappings.

Here is an MSDN Blog article abou how to do it.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-enable-ssl-on-a-sharepoint-web-application.aspx

At a high level, here are the steps:

1. Go to CA and under Web Application Management select Configure Alternate Access Mappings
2. Select the web application you wish to manage.
3. Add a new HTTPS URL and choose a new zone.
4. Add an SSL certificate/HTTPS binding to IIS.